# Cloudera, Oracle JDK and Open JDK

Tags: java, oracle, cloudera-cdh

It is mandatory to have Oracle JDK instead of Open JDK to install the libraries of cloudera to make cloudera cluster on redhat machine?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, only Oracle JDK releases are *certified* for use with Cloudera products; see

- [Cloudera Enterprise 6 Release Guide](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/release-notes/topics/rg_release_notes.html) > [Requirements and Supported Versions](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/release-notes/topics/rg_requirements_supported_versions.html) > [Java Requirements](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/release-notes/topics/rg_java_requirements.html#java_requirements)

In the future this may change.  According to a Cloudera employee reply to  a Cloudera Community posting.

> Re: OpenJDK certification for CDH
>
> "Lingesh" - 10-31-2018 03:35 AM
>
> There is currently work-in-progress thing to certify some of the OpenJDK versions against Cloudera suite of products. We can expect the official announcement once the testing and certification are complete for the future CM/CDH releases.

([link](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/CDH-Manual-Installation/OpenJDK-certification-for-CDH/td-p/77166))

---

Of course, even now you *could* ignore this requirement and use an OpenJDK Java or some other non-Oracle Java.  But if you encountered problems, Cloudera Support may not be able to help you.